# Kill switch for car lights

Tags: mercedes-benz, relay, switches, sl500

I'm trying to add a kill switch that will turn off ALL the lights in my car. My car has a light control module that consists of a bunch of relays that controls all the lights.

My plan is to splice a 12V on/off switch to the wire that comes out of the light relay and put it into the dashboard of my car. Is this flawed?

Do I need an extra relay in addition to the switch? What kind of relay do I need? What kind of switch do I need? What kind of wires do I need to use? Anything to watch out for? Possible things that might go wrong?

Car is Mercedes benz SL500 1997 (R129)
Let me know if you need more information.
Here are the fuse box details
[image]

This is the module that's in the fuse box
https://www.ebay.com/itm/374000492257

[image]
I don't exactly know which wire I need to splice or how to even figure out which one.

Wiring diagrams:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's kind of hard to answer without knowing how your car is wired. disrupting the power to the headlamp relay coils can be done with thinner wire and smaller switches than disrupting the power that flows from the relays to the lamps.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not exactly sure how MB does it, but a lot of vehicles use what's called a Body Control Module (BCM) to control most of the lights in a vehicle. The thing is, the BCM also controls other functions, such as windows, door locks, mirror/seat presets, and possibly a lot more. If you cut power to this, you kill a LOT of other functions in your vehicle. Using a BCM is fairly standard. If you are doing this to black out a vehicle, you might want to get one which isn't as complicated - MB's are extremely complicated electronically.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks paul. From my understanding however, the low beam headlights and rear taillights are not on the BCM but they are on the light control module pictured above in the post (ebay link). So it should be possible to at the very least kill those 2 lights. I'm just not confident enough how to.

Comment: What do you mean by "ALL the lights in my car"? I don't think we are on the same sheet of music.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Basically every light controlled by the light module. I think the brake lights and turn signal lights and reverse lights are on the BCM like you said, so they won't be able to be turned off with the rest of the lights.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Fixed. Need more diagrams? I think diagram 1 has every light I need to deal with.

Comment: Really, I'm not sure the diagrams help at all ... they don't show wire color ... though, if they had wire color, I bet you wouldn't be asking the question in first place ;o) I think your best bet is to test to see which leads are powered, one at a time. Then disconnect them as you find them powered, and see what happens. Is going to be quite labor intensive, but might work out well for you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Say I found the 3-4 wires I need to do the job, how do I splice them to add a switch? Do I need a switch for every wire I splice or can I route them all to 1 switch? How do I do it and would I need to add an extra relay too?

Comment: Should just be one switch, just to interrupt the flow. If you have a 12v switch which will can handle the amperage (check the fuse, make it the same), it should be able to handle it just fine. My bet is, anything coming out of here is actuating a relay, so a minimal amperage switch is needed. Getting a larger than needed switch will not harm anything and could help if the amperage is greater than you think it should be.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I just accessed the module and took it out and examined the wires with the keys turned so the electrical system is on. I have no idea how I'm supposed to figure out which wire it is when I have to disconnect the relay to get to the wires in the first place so they turn off. Do I use a voltmeter? But in that case a lot of the wires have 12V so still it doesn't tell me anything :(

Comment: so "all the lights," but not really all the lights?

Comment: @TigerGuy All the lights on the light module